# Difference between a mollifier and a radial mollifier

Tags: real-analysis

What is the difference between a mollifier and a radial mollifier ? I have the impression that the standard mollifier (i.e. $\varphi(x)=ce^{\frac{1}{1-|x|^2}}$ is radial), but what would be a non radial mollifier ?

Comment: I think there would be plenty of them. Just variate the radial mollifier a bit w.r.t. the direction? For example, let $f(x)$ be a Gaussian pdf with distinct radiuses, then how about $c'f(x)\phi(x)$?